# What are the requirements of gnu-parallel to/for a remote device that is contacted via ssh (and public-key authentication)

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am using gnu-parallel.

I assume there is a problem with my environment.
**What I want to achieve:**
Trying to execute a command on multiple machines.
For that I've created a sshloginfile (aptly named ~/.parallel/sshloginfile) with some entries like:

```
#  define hostgroup debian
@debian/5-1.p
@debian/6-1.p
@debian/7-1.p
...
#  define hostgroup qnap with only 1 cpu
1/@qnap/4-1.a
#  define hostgroup macos
@macos/33-1.w
#  local computer
@macos/:
```

The names (5-1.p, 6-1.p, ...) behind the hostgroups (@debian, @qnap, ...) are entries in the ~/.ssh/config. All ssh connections are authenticated via public key authentication.

As a simple command I would like to see the uptime:

```
parallel --jobs 0 --nonall --tag --slf .. uptime
```

works beautifully

```
:   19:25  up 4 days, 23:02, 3 users, load averages: 2.14 1.86 1.79
5-1.p    19:25:27 up 23 days, 18:54,  0 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.13, 0.18
6-1.p    19:26:04 up 20:05,  0 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.08, 0.10
4-1.a   sh: line 0: exec: perl: not found
```

except for one host (4.1-a), which is a QNAP storage system.

To my surprise, the command *not* using the sshloginfile but instead directly addressing this one server *does* work:

```
parallel --jobs 0 --nonall --tag ssh 4-1.a uptime
```

outputs:

```
19:28:37 up 16 days,  8:24, load average: 0.72, 0.61, 0.59
```

So there seems to be a dependency/prerequisite that needs to be fulfilled if a device is addressed via sshloginfile, which is not necessary otherwise. And it seems to be perl, which is in fact not installed on the QNAP storage system.
Does anybody have a clue why this would be?

Version of parallel: GNU parallel 20181222
os version of host: Darwin 18.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Mon Nov 12 20:24:46 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.231.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 [macOS 10.14.2]
os version of working devices: Linux 4.14.90+ #1183 Fri Dec 21 13:50:04 GMT 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux
os version of "problematic" device 4-1.a: Linux 3.4.6 #1 Wed Jan 2 07:02:07 CST 2019 armv5tel unknown

Addendum: The man page states:
DEPENDENCIES
       GNU parallel uses Perl, and the Perl modules Getopt::Long, IPC::Open3, Symbol, IO::File, POSIX, and File::Temp. For remote usage it also uses rsync with ssh.

rsync is installed on the "problematic" device.

Comment: I dono, I tend to use `xargs -P` instead so that may be a workaround for you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! :)
  Since I am trying to learn gnu-parallel I would like to understand what is necessary on the remote side to execute commands with gnu-parallel.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel has since 20150122 depended on `perl` being installed on the remote system.

What you are seeing suggests to me that the `qnap` server does not have Perl installed.

If you run:

```
parallel -vvS server echo ::: foo
parallel -vvS server --wd ...  --trc {}.foo touch {}.foo ::: *
```

you will see what GNU Parallel is actually running. As you can see that is rather complex and includes a Perl script. This is the reason why Perl is needed on the remote system.

For further details on this read: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#The-remote-system-wrapper

My guess is that:

```
parallel -S 1/4-1.a echo ::: foo
```

will also result in:

```
sh: line 0: exec: perl: not found
```

So the solution is probably to install perl on `qnap`.

Comment: Thank you. I already assumed perl was the problem (as in "And it seems to be perl, which is in fact not installed on the QNAP storage system.") but I was surprised that  "parallel --jobs 0 --nonall --tag ssh 4-1.a uptime" worked (even without perl).

Comment: In `parallel --jobs 0 --nonall --tag ssh 4-1.a uptime` the `ssh` command is being run on the local machine.